# Sending a value to the database without rendering the Flask template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a gallery of images that load dynamically with Flask. Each image has a bookmark button that updates the database when I click it. The problem is that it renders the template each time I click it and refreshes the page, which is annoying for the user. I don't know much about Javascript/JQuery/Ajax, but I tried to code something by following the Flask documentation. I really don't have a clue if what I did is totally wrong or if I'm close to something. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="position-relative">
   <!-- Loads the image and generates its HTML id (database image id (image[0]) + 'img') -->
   <img class="card-img-top card-img-bottom thumb"
    src="{{ url_for('static',filename=image[1]) }}" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'img' }}">
</div>

<!-- If image[2] is true the image has already been bookmarked and the bookmark icons loads solid, else it loads regular -->
{% if image[2]: %}

<!-- The divs iconBookb and iconBookn will toggle from display:block to none and vice-versa when the bookmark button is clicked --> 
<div id="iconBookb" style="display:block;">
    <a class="btn-floating bookmark" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'ims' }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i></a>
</div>
<div id="iconBookn" style="display:none;">
    <a class="btn-floating bookmark" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'imr' }}"><i class="regular fa-bookmark"></i></a>
</div>
{% else %}

<!-- The code after 'else' won't load initially if the image is bookmarked, so there won't be ID conflict with the divs before the 'else' -->
<div id="iconBookb" style="display:block;">
   <a class="btn-floating bookmark" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'ims' }}"><i class="fa-regular fa-bookmark"></i></a>
</div>
<div id="iconBookn" style="display:none;">
   <a class="btn-floating bookmark" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'imr' }}"><i class="solid fa-bookmark"></i></a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

JQuery/AJAX:

```
$(function() {
   $('.bookmark').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/bookmarking', {
          // Gets the id of the 'button' I clicked and removes the last three characters so what's left is the database id of the image
          var img_id = $(this).attr('id').slice(0,-3);
          // Converts it to an integer (don't know if it's necessary)
          image_id: parseInt(img_id)
          // Toggle visibility of the divs
       }, function() {
            $("#iconBookb").toggle();
            $("#iconBookn").toggle();
           });
       });
   });
```

Python code:

```
@blueprint.route('/bookmark', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bookmarking():
    image_id = request.args.get('image_id')
    image_to_bookmark = db.session.query(AImages).get(image_id)
    if not image_to_bookmark.bookmark:
        image_to_bookmark.bookmark = True
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        image_to_bookmark.bookmark = False
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: If your `onclick` handler returns false, the browser's normal action (that is, refreshing the page) will be cancelled.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried that, it cancels the page refresh but the button doesn't update the database

Comment: What is `{{ image[0] - 'imr' }}` supposed to do?  Did you mean `+` here?

Comment: Yes, in Flask you have to use ~ instead of +